# Game maker android Build - Gradlew

Tags: android, gradlew, aapt, game-maker

I set up my phone and the environment to develop for Android and tested everything in Android Studio perfectly. I created an app on Game Maker: Studio and pressinei F5 only when the project is to be executed in Gradlew the error occurs:

```
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1.
```

Follow output of the GMS:

```
    Compile started: 14:32:01
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\gamemaker_studio\GMAssetCompiler.exe" /fU="C:\Users\####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\a9408.txt" /c /m=android /studio  /config="Default" /tgt=8 /obob=True /obpp=False /obru=True /obes=False /i=3 /cvm /tp=1024 /mv=1 /iv=0 /rv=0 /bv=1757 /gn="###-#####-#" /td="C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local" /cd="C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache" /sh=True /dbgp="6502" /hip="192.168.0.14" /hprt="51268" /o="C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\###-#####-#" /optionsini="C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\gm_ttt_98820\###-#####-#.ini"   "C:\workspace\###-#####-#.gmx\###-#####-#.project.gmx"

Reading project file....finished.
Compile Constants...finished.
Remove DnD...finished.
Compile Scripts...finished.
Compile Objects...finished.
Compile Timelines...finished.
Compile Triggers...finished.
Compile Rooms...finished.
Compile Extensions...finished.
Final Compile...finished.
Saving IFF file... C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\###-#####-#\###-#####-#.zip
Writing Chunk... GEN8
Writing Chunk... OPTN
Writing Chunk... EXTN
Writing Chunk... SOND
Writing Chunk... AGRP
Writing Chunk... SPRT
Writing Chunk... BGND
Writing Chunk... PATH
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... SHDR
Writing Chunk... FONT
Writing Chunk... TMLN
Writing Chunk... OBJT
Writing Chunk... ROOM
Writing Chunk... DAFL
Writing Chunk... TPAGE
Writing Chunk... CODE
Writing Chunk... VARI
Writing Chunk... FUNC
Writing Chunk... STRG
Writing Chunk... TXTR
0 Compressing texture... writing texture texture_0.png... 
1 Compressing texture... writing texture texture_1.png... 
Writing Chunk... AUDO
Writing Chunk... SCPT
Writing Chunk... DBGI
Writing Chunk... INST
Writing Chunk... LOCL
Writing Chunk... STRG
Stats : GMA : Elapsed=1946,5837
Stats : GMA : sp=65,au=0,bk=2,pt=0,sc=27,sh=0,fo=3,tl=0,ob=47,ro=4,da=0,ex=2,ma=305,fm=0x5DF802F0
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" get-state 

device
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $INTERNAL_STORAGE

 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

/sdcard "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" get-state 

device
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $INTERNAL_STORAGE

 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE

/sdcard "c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell mkdir -p "/sdcard/GMstudio" 

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" shell rm -f "/sdcard/GMstudio/options.ini"

"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" push "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\###-#####-#\\GameAssetsDROID.zip" /sdcard/GMstudio/GameAssetsDROID.zip

4496 KB/s (299309 bytes in 0.065s)
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb" push "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Local\gm_ttt_6046\###-#####-#\\GameDownload.lock" /sdcard/GMstudio/GameDownload.lock

0 KB/s (13 bytes in 0.013s)
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb"  shell cat /system/build.prop 

 # begin build properties # autogenerated by buildinfo.sh ro.build.id=MRA58K ro.build.display.id=Q2.BR.OPEN.L2016070401 ro.internal.version=D5110_INFINIX_A1M_C1_V0.4.0_S1214 ro.build.version.incremental=URBRL2016070401 ro.build.version.sdk=23 ro.build.version.preview_sdk=0 ro.build.version.codename=REL ro.build.version.all_codenames=REL ro.build.version.release=6.0 ro.build.version.security_patch=2016-06-01 ro.build.version.base_os= ro.build.date=Thu Jul  7 10:43:12 BRT 2016 ro.build.date.utc=1467898992 ro.build.type=user ro.build.user=android ro.build.host=quantum ro.build.tags=release-keys ro.build.flavor=full_j5805_m_quantum-user ro.product.model=Quantum Go ro.product.brand=Quantum ro.product.name=Q2 ro.product.device=Q2 ro.product.board=Q2 # ro.product.cpu.abi and ro.product.cpu.abi2 are obsolete, # use ro.product.cpu.abilist instead. ro.product.cpu.abi=arm64-v8a ro.product.cpu.abilist=arm64-v8a,armeabi-v7a,armeabi ro.product.cpu.abilist32=armeabi-v7a,armeabi ro.product.cpu.abilist64=arm64-v8a ro.product.manufacturer=Quantum ro.product.locale=pt-BR ro.wifi.channels= ro.board.platform=mt6753 # ro.build.product is obsolete; use ro.product.device ro.build.product=Q2 # Do not try to parse description, fingerprint, or thumbprint ro.build.description=full_j5805_m_quantum-user 6.0 MRA58K URBRL2016070401 release-keys ro.build.fingerprint=Quantum/Q2/Q2:6.0/MRA58K/URBRL2016070401:user/release-keys ro.build.characteristics=default ro.mtp.label=Quantum Go ro.ptp.label=Quantum Go # end build properties # # from device/ratech/j5805_m_quantum/system.prop # # # system.prop for generic sdk #  rild.libpath=mtk-ril.so rild.libargs=-d /dev/ttyC0  #Add for NVRAM (Start) @{ ro.rgk_nvram_lid=71 #Add for NVRAM (End) }@  # MTK, Infinity, 20090720 { wifi.interface=wlan0 # MTK, Infinity, 20090720 }  # MTK, mtk03034, 20101210 { ro.mediatek.wlan.wsc=1 # MTK, mtk03034 20101210} # MTK, mtk03034, 20110318 { ro.mediatek.wlan.p2p=1 # MTK, mtk03034 20110318}  # MTK, mtk03034, 20101213 { mediatek.wlan.ctia=0 # MTK, mtk03034 20101213}   # wifi.tethering.interface=ap0 #  ro.opengles.version=196608  wifi.direct.interface=p2p0 dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=256m dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m  # USB MTP WHQL ro.sys.usb.mtp.whql.enable=0  # Power off opt in IPO sys.ipo.pwrdncap=2  ro.sys.usb.storage.type=mtp  # USB BICR function ro.sys.usb.bicr=no  # USB Charge only function ro.sys.usb.charging.only=yes  # audio ro.camera.sound.forced=0 ro.audio.silent=0  ro.zygote.preload.enable=0  # temporary enables NAV bar (soft keys) qemu.hw.mainkeys=0  ro.kernel.zio=38,108,105,16 #ro.kernel.qemu=1 #ro.kernel.qemu.gles=0 #ro.boot.selinux=disable  # Disable dirty region for Mali debug.hwui.render_dirty_regions=false  ro.sf.lcd_density=320  # performance ro.mtk_perf_simple_start_win=1 ro.mtk_perf_fast_start_win=1 ro.mtk_perf_response_time=1  # # ADDITIONAL_BUILD_PROPERTIES # persist.sys.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo persist.sys.usb.config=mtp ro.adb.secure=1 ro.setupwizard.mode=OPTIONAL ro.com.google.gmsversion=6.0_r4 ro.com.google.clientidbase=android-positivo ro.config.ringtone=Ring_Synth_04.ogg ro.config.notification_sound=pixiedust.ogg ro.carrier=unknown ro.config.alarm_alert=Alarm_Classic.ogg dalvik.vm.heapgrowthlimit=256m dalvik.vm.heapsize=512m ro.mediatek.chip_ver=S01 ro.mediatek.version.release=alps-mp-m0.mp1-V2.39.1_rgk6753.65u.m0 ro.mediatek.platform=MT6735 ro.telephony.sim.count=2 persist.radio.default.sim=0 persist.radio.multisim.config=dsds persist.gemini.sim_num=2 ro.gemini.smart_sim_switch=false ril.specific.sm_cause=0 bgw.current3gband=0 ril.external.md=0 ro.mtk_cam_lomo_support=1 ro.sf.hwrotation=0 curlockscreen=0 ro.mediatek.gemini_support=true persist.radio.fd.counter=15 persist.radio.fd.off.counter=5 persist.radio.fd.r8.counter=15 persist.radio.fd.off.r8.counter=5 drm.service.enabled=true fmradio.driver.enable=1 ril.first.md=1 ril.flightmode.poweroffMD=1 ril.telephony.mode=0 dalvik.vm.mtk-stack-trace-file=/data/anr/mtk_traces.txt mediatek.wlan.chip=CONSYS_MT6735 mediatek.wlan.module.postfix=_consys_mt6735 ril.read.imsi=1 ril.radiooff.poweroffMD=0 ro.frp.pst=/dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/frp ro.mediatek.version.branch=alps-mp-m0.mp1 ro.mediatek.version.sdk=4 ro.mtk_gemini_support=1 persist.radio.gemini_support=1 ril.current.share_modem=2 ro.mtk_audio_profiles=1 ro.mtk_audenh_support=1 ro.mtk_besloudness_support=1 ro.mtk_bessurround_support=1 ro.mtk_wapi_support=1 ro.mtk_bt_support=1 ro.mtk_agps_app=1 ro.mtk_voice_ui_support=1 ro.mtk_voice_unlock_support=1 ro.mtk_audio_tuning_tool_ver=V1 ro.mtk_wlan_support=1 ro.mtk_ipo_support=1 ro.mtk_gps_support=1 ro.mtk_omacp_support=1 ro.mtk_search_db_support=1 ro.mtk_dialer_search_support=1 ro.mtk_dhcpv6c_wifi=1 ro.have_aacencode_feature=1 ro.mtk_fd_support=1 ro.mtk_oma_drm_support=1 ro.mtk_widevine_drm_l3_support=1 ro.mtk_eap_sim_aka=1 ro.mtk_fm_recording_support=1 ro.mtk_audio_ape_support=1 ro.mtk_flv_playback_support=1 ro.mtk_wmv_playback_support=1 ro.mtk_send_rr_support=1 ro.mtk_emmc_support=1 ro.mtk_tetheringipv6_support=1 ro.mtk_shared_sdcard=1 ro.mtk_enable_md1=1 ro.mtk_afw_support=1 ro.mtk_flight_mode_power_off_md=1 ro.mtk_pq_support=2 ro.mtk_miravision_support=1 ro.mtk_miravision_image_dc=1 ro.mtk_wfd_support=1 ro.mtk_wfd_sink_support=1 ro.mtk_wfd_sink_uibc_support=1 ro.mtk_wifi_mcc_support=1 ro.mtk_sim_hot_swap=1 ro.mtk_thumbnail_play_support=1 ro.mtk_bip_scws=1 ro.mtk_world_phone_policy=0 ro.mtk_perfservice_support=1 ro.mtk_mobile_management=1 ro.mtk_antibricking_level=2 ro.mtk_zsdhdr_support=1 ro.mtk_cam_mfb_support=3 ro.mtk_slow_motion_support=1 ro.mtk_lte_support=1 ro.mtk_cam_vfb=1 ro.mtk_rild_read_imsi=1 ro.sim_refresh_reset_by_modem=1 ro.mtk_passpoint_r1_support=1 ro.mtk_bg_power_saving_support=1 ro.mtk_bg_power_saving_ui=1 ro.have_aee_feature=1 ro.sim_me_lock_mode=0 ro.mtk_dual_mic_support=0 ro.mtk_is_tablet=0 ro.mtk_ims_support=1 ro.mtk_volte_support=1 persist.mtk.volte.enable=1 persist.dbg.volte_avail_ovr=1 ro.mtk_user_root_switch=1 ro.mtk_voice_extension_support=1 wfd.dummy.enable=1 ro.mediatek.project.path=device/ratech/j5805_m_quantum persist.mtk.wcn.combo.chipid=-1 service.wcn.driver.ready=no service.wcn.coredump.mode=2 ro.com.android.mobiledata=false persist.radio.mobile.data=0,0 persist.meta.dumpdata=0 ro.mtk_deinterlace_support=1 ro.mtk_md_sbp_custom_value=18 persist.mtk.datashaping.support=1 persist.datashaping.alarmgroup=1 ro.rgk_em_assistant_screenoff=1 ro.rgk_number_min_match=7 persist.sys.dalvik.vm.lib.2=libart dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.variant=cortex-a53 dalvik.vm.isa.arm64.features=default dalvik.vm.isa.arm.variant=cortex-a53 dalvik.vm.isa.arm.features=default net.bt.name=Android dalvik.vm.stack-trace-file=/data/anr/traces.txt ro.expect.recovery_id=0x9355812e8928e90681bdf428fe75696dce19165c000000000000000000000000 FastCreate started: 14:32:07
FastCreate End File Copies: 14:32:07
cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\gamemaker_studio\Android\runner\gradle\gradlew"" build -x assembleDebug

:com.companyname.###-#####-#:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:checkReleaseManifest
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42311Library UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:prepareReleaseDependencies
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:processReleaseResourcesC:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:2 : Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:34 : Tag <application> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:38 : Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:51 : Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':com.companyname.###-#####-#:processReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.443 secs
FastCreate End End: 14:32:21
Compile finished: 14:32:21
```

Where I run the command Gradlew with "--stacktrace" I believe that MSG is creating the project structure somewhere in the appdata where would it be? Has anyone experienced this problem before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i noticed those lines :

```
:com.companyname.###-#####-#:processReleaseResourcesC:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:2 : Tag <manifest> attribute package has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:34 : Tag <application> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:38 : Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
C:\Users\#####\Documents\GameMaker\Cache\###-#####-#\Android\Default\com.companyname.###-#####-#\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:51 : Tag <activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.
```

the error seems to be `<activity> attribute name has invalid character '-'.` on lines 34, 38, 51 on your manifest `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: You're right! I goes to Global Game Settings and change in Android / Fire  ( test) "Package Name". 
In my old package Name I've a "-".